# VS 2008 QuickWatch option

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following function that was written in c++:

```
int CompareStrings(IN const string& str1, IN const string& str2)
{
return str1.compare(str2);
}
```

I want at run time to debug it, but when I try to add watch this line str1.compare(str2);, I receive "CXX0052: Error: member function not present",

does anyone know why?

Comment: The compiler probably inlines it out of existence, or replaces it with string.compare where it's called.

Comment: and what can I do to debug it?

Comment: There's nothing to debug, unless `string` is not `std::string`, in which case you should put a breakpoint in the implementation of your string class.

Comment: What is the `IN` in the parameter declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int CompareStrings(IN const string& str1, IN const string& str2)
{
 int x = str1.compare(str2);
 return x;
}
```

One way is to simply do above. In Debug unoptimized build you will have **x** to watch and inspect and in Release build it will be optimized away.

In **Visual Studio 2011** you can actually do **s1.compare(s2)** in the debugger :) and view the results